# Gibt es ein Fremdwort für das Wort »Fremdwort«?

Tags: single-word-request, terminology, loanword

Mit welchem Fremdwort (fremdsprachlicher Ausdruck) könnte man das deutsche Wort *Fremdwort* wiedergeben?

Der Duden hält sich bei der Frage komplett bedeckt. Wikipedia bzw. Wiktionary gibt die Unterbegriffe *Exotismus, Xenismus, Xenographie, Zitatwort* an, die aber offenbar bis auf *Xenismus* eher fachsprachlicher Natur sind. *Xenismus* klingt mir jedoch zu konstruiert. Gibt es weitere Alternativen?

*Xenismus* wirkt auf mich zu konstruiert, weil die Moneme zu unreflektiert gewählt und anschließend verbunden scheinen. Es macht auf mich den Eindruck eines schlechten Kofferworts. (Klar sind *Xeno-* und *-ismus* hier (traditionsbedingt) die Moneme der Wahl, allerdings wünschte ich mir hier eine *rundere* Verbindung, die sich leichter über die Lippen bringen lässt. Darauf muss aber an dieser Stelle nicht eingegangen werden. Ich bin zunächst einfach nur an Alternativen interessiert, die es noch geben könnte.)

Im Prinzip möchte ich das Fremdwort für *Fremdwort* wie *Fremdwort* verwenden können, also (im semantosyntaktischen Sinne) hinsichtlich Konnexion und Kollokativität, was aber in erster Linie nachrangig ist. Stilistisch ist das *Fremdwort* als Fremdwort natürlich per se höher angesiedelt, aber an sich sollte es sich so verwenden lassen, dass nicht gleich der Eindruck von *Extraterrestrik* entsteht.

Ich suche also ein Wort, dass man so ähnlich (wie möglich) wie *Fremdwort* benutzen kann, aber eben ein Fremdwort ist.

Comment: Ad hoc fallen mir nur Begriffe zu speziellen Fremdwörtern ein: [Anglizismus](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglizismus), Latinismus, [Gallizismus](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallizismus)... Es gibt auch [Lehnwörter](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehnwort)

Comment: Warum suchst Du so ein Wort? Bitte [edit]iere Deine Frage dahingegehnd, sodass wir besser abschätzen können, ob Wörter Deinen Kriterien genügen und warum *Xenismus* zu konstruiert ist.

Comment: Ich weiss zwar nicht, warum man ausgerechnet ein Fremdwort suchen muss, wenn man ein sehr treffendes deutsches Wort hat, aber *Xenologismus* habe ich schon gehört (mich aber nicht drüber gefreut...)

Comment: Natürlich ist es im Allgemeinen ratsam deutsche Wörter Fremdwörtern vorzuziehen, aber im Sinne der Diversifizierung des Idiolekts (wohlgemerkt aufgrund des Variationsgedanken oder Facettenreichtums der Eigenrede) hat es schon seine Berechtigung. Scherzhaft finde ich so ein Wort auch ziemlich erheiternd (bei entsprechendem Publikum natürlich ;-) ). Auf jeden Fall bekommt *Xenologismus* meinen grünen Haken. Danach habe ich gesucht!

Comment: "Ich muss hier leider den Teufelsanwalt spielen, und die Gegenfrage stellen, warum du überhaupt danach suchst?"
"Es gibt also so gut wie keine geschichtliche Notwendigkeit, für das Wort Fremdwort ein Fremdwort zu erfinden" Dafür gibt es doch eine klare Antwort, weswegen auch ich hierher gelangt bin: Ironie.

Comment: "Barbarismus" trifft vermutlich nicht den Kern der Frage und dürfte zudem kaum mehr als Fremdwort durchgehen. Dezwegen bleibt es bei nem Kommentar.

Answer (score 8):

Ich muss hier leider den Teufelsanwalt spielen, und die Gegenfrage stellen, warum du überhaupt danach suchst? Es gibt ein eindeutiges, unmissverständliches Wort für »ein Wort, das aus einer anderen Sprache in die eigene – hier: das Deutsche – übernommen wurde«: Das Wort *Fremdwort.* Zwar bin ich kein Sprachwissenschaftler und habe keinen Zugang zu ebensolcher Forschung, der über das Lesen von Wikipediaeinträgen hinausginge, aber da der besagte Eintrag außer dem Wort *Fremdwort* kein anderes enthält, erscheint es mir, als würde auch in der Fachsprache kein solches verwendet.

Warum werden Fremdwörter gerne eingesetzt? Manche benützen sie weil sie es gewohnt sind; weil in ihrer Umgebung ständig fachsprachliche Ausdrücke benutzt werden, obwohl sie in der Umgangssprache kaum vorkommen – deswegen existiert dafür der Ausdruck *Fachchinesisch.* Andere wollen vielleicht zeigen, wie klug sie sind, oder wie dumm das Gegenüber – Erstes dadurch, dass sie wissen, wie das Wort richtig verwendet wird, Letzes, indem es schlichtweg nicht verstanden wird. Beides wird von der Umgebung (außerhalb des direkten Umfeldes zum Beispiel des Hochschullehrertreffens) in der Regel nicht wertgeschätzt; im Gegenteil. Die Erhöhung der eigenen Position oder die Erniedrigung jener des Anderen wird vom Empfänger eher beleidigend aufgefasst.

Vielleicht gibt es auch einen dritten Fall, in welchem man das oben angesprochene Fachchinesisch durch den Kakao ziehen möchte. Bekannt sind scherzhaft gemeinte Aussagen wie:

> Ballistische Experimente mit kristallin-komprimierten Dihydrogenmonoxidproben unterliegen auf dem Exteriorgelände der pädagogischen Anstalt striktester Prohibition!

Oder, auf gut Deutsch:

> Schneeballwerfen auf dem Schulhof ist verboten!

Solche Scherze gelingen, wenn die Zuhörer sich einen Reim auf die verwendeten Ausdrücke machen können. Das ist dann der Fall, wenn die Wörter – so sie in ihrer besonderen Bedeutung nicht sofort bekannt sind – zumindest auf bekannte Wurzeln zurückführbar sind. *Exteriorgelände* erschließt sich zum Beispiel über den Umweg des englischen *exterior* oder vergleichbaren Wörtern im Französischen, Spanischen, Lateinischen oder Italienischen. Es wird sogar in einer sozusagend passenden Bedeutung dort verwendet. Der »Übertragungsweg« ist kurz.

Machen wir uns also die Mühe, und schauen wie *Fremdwort* in andere Sprachen übersetzt wird – weil ich nicht alle Übersetzungen sofort parat habe, richte ich mich nach denjenigen, die auf der [deutschen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Fremdwort) beziehungsweise [englischen Wiktionaryseite](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/loanword) für [*Fremdwort*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Fremdwort) oder [*loan word*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/loanword) niedergeschrieben wurden. Es fällt auf, dass in den meisten Sprachen irgendeine Zusammensetzung der Wurzeln *fremd* oder *leihen* mit dem entsprechenden Wort für *Wort* auftaucht:

- *loanword* (englisch; *geliehenes Wort*)
- *mot étranger* oder *emprunt* (französisch; *fremdes Wort* oder *Beleihung;* ob letzeres stimmt kann ich nicht sagen)
- *δάνειο* (griechisch; *Beleihung*)
- *parola straniera* (italienisch; *fremdes Wort*)
- *lainasana* (finnisch; *geliehenes Wort*)
- 外来語 (がいらいご, *gairaigo;* japanisch; *Auslandswort*)
- lånord (schwedisch; *Leihwort*)
- *leenwoord* (niederländisch; gleicher Ursprung wie das deutsche *Lehnwort*)
- *låneord* (dänisch; *Leihwort*)
- *vocabulum peregrinum* (latein; *ausländisches Wort*)

Sollte ich eine Übertragung falsch interpretiert haben (ich bin in der Hauptsache den entsprechenden verlinkten Einträgen gefolgt) bitte ich um Verbesserung!

In den anderen Sprachen kann ich die einzelnen Begriffe nicht auf etwas bekanntes zurückführen. Nichts davon sieht jedoch lateinisch oder griechisch aus – die übliche Art, ein Fremdwort zu erkennen. Demnach gibt es in so gut wie keiner Sprache eine fremdsprachiges Wort, das *Fremdwort* bedeutet – wozu auch? Fremdwörter werden in der Regel von außerhalb eingeführt um einen bestimmten Sachverhalt darzustellen, für den man meint, kein passendes Wort in der eigenen Sprache vorrätig zu haben. Ein *Fremdwort* ist aber kein klar abgegrenzter Sachverhalt, zu dessen Beschreibung ein neues – eben fremdes – Wort gebraucht würde. Wenn man ein Wort wie *Fremdwort* braucht, dann um zu erklären, dass ein *anderes* Wort ein ebensolches ist – und dafür haben die Begriffe der eigenen Sprache anscheinend und offensichtlich bisher stets ausgereicht.

Es gibt also so gut wie keine geschichtliche Notwendigkeit, für das Wort *Fremdwort* ein Fremdwort zu erfinden, und es gibt keinen entsprechenden, gefestigten fremdsprachlichen Ausdruck dafür. Es gibt keine Lücke, die durch ein ausländisches Wort für *Fremdwort* zu füllen wäre. Folglich gibt es – zurecht – kein gutes Fremdwort für *Fremdwort.*

Answer (score 0):

"Altera-linguales Synonym" wäre eine Option. Ich weiß, ist schon etwas her, aber wollte es nur gesagt haben :D